# Changing Inno Setup manifest

Tags: inno-setup

Using Inno Setup version 5.2.3.
I need to update the manifest resource that is embedded in my setup.exe.

I need to add some features required by a compatibility testing program used by our client:

```
  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
    <application>
      <supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}"/>
      <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>
      <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"/>
    </application>
  </compatibility>
```

I know there is an `OutputManifestFile` key. but is there an `InputManifestFile` or similar?

Comment: Why not using latest version of inno Setup?

Comment: @Slappy, Is this option supported with newer inno Setup?

Comment: Yup, [`these are there`](http://i.imgur.com/grVdiNP.png) (output from v.5.5.4).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those GUIDs represent "my application is fully compatible with (and tested on) these versions of Windows".  Patching the resource on an old version of an Inno installer would be lying, and you should not do that.

Instead, you should upgrade to the latest version of Inno.  This already contains these GUIDs in its manifest because it has indeed been updated and tested on those versions of Windows.

Note that similar rules apply to your application: you should not include those values in your application's manifest without committing to test on those versions.

Comment: I see your point (and it's a valid one). However I would have expected Inno to have an option to set a *custom* manifest, and be able to add/edit any entry in the manifest structure... just saying. I ended up patching `Setup.e32` and `SetupLdr.e32` with ResHack. When I'll have more time I will upgrade Inno.

Comment: Have you verified the binary output after you patched the `Setup.e32` and `SetupLdr.e32` files ? I think you'll be disapointed. Just upgrade to the latest version. Version you're currently using is fully compatible with the most recent one, so you'll have no extra work with migration.

Comment: @TLama, Yes I have verified it (after signing it) and all is good. why do you think "you'll be disappointed"?

Comment: Because I've tried the same and no change were propagated to the output binary file manifest.

Comment: @TLama, well maybe you patched the wrong files? output setup.exe contains the manifest I have changed + the testing program stopped complaining about this issue. My main concern about newer versions of Inno is with ISPP. will it work OK without re-installing? also it has to be NON-Unicode version of Inno.

Comment: I've patched the right files, but now I figured out the reason. I've made changes to those *.e32 binaries in a separate directory where I've had a mirror of Inno Setup and when running the compiler, that little beast took the files from its home program files folder. About upgrade; preprocessor became part of the Inno Setup since version 5.4 and ANSI version is available even for the most recent one, so you should have no problem at all.

Comment: @ZigiZ: yes, ISPP will still work on the latest version, as will ANSI mode.  Just make sure you download the right installer.  (You don't need the QSP for ISPP any more, though it doesn't hurt.)  Upgrading Inno is generally painless and takes no more than a couple of minutes.  (In very rare cases you have to make minor changes to your script, which are documented in the changelog.)